# How to show PIN/ Password in Bootstrap pincode-input.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap pincode-input.js to display PIN for my web app. I want my pin to be masked initially. But when the user click show button I want them to see the PIN. Can somebody help me how to do this. Thanks in advance.

```
<input type="text" id="pincode-input">        
    <br />
    <br />
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnShow">Show</a>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {           
            $('#pincode-input').pincodeInput({
                hidedigits: true, inputs: 4
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Try to add Click event to pincode-input and then in the event set the property hidedigits on false if it's true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never used this plugin but on 1st look at their demo page they mask/hide numbers with

```
.pincode-input-text-masked {
  font-family: pincode-input-mask;
}
```

simple you can do button function similar to this to show the numbers

```
$('button').click(function(){
$('.pincode-input-text-masked').css({"font-family": "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"});
})
```

Comment: @MukhlisurRahman if this is what you looking for accept my answer to mark this topic as solved